# AppState listener continues to work even though I remove it

Tags: javascript, react-native, listener

I added a listener to screen A as you can see below. But when I navigate to screen B, I see that this listener is still running. How can I solve this problem?

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import { Button, AppState } from "react-native"
import { MainRoutes } from "../../navigation/routes"


const ScreenA = ({ navigation }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const appStateListener = AppState.addEventListener('change', state => console.log(state));
        return () => appStateListener.remove();
    }, [])


    return (
        <Button
            title={"Next"}
            onPress={() => {
                navigation.reset({
                    index: 0,
                    routes: [{ name: MainRoutes.ScreenB }],
                })
            }} />
    )
}

export default ScreenA
```

Comment: This app state listener will be removed when the component unmounts, i.e. when you close the app. To cancel subscription when you navigate away from screen use navigation [event listeners](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle)

Comment: Am I not already stopping the listener on unmount the way I wrote it? I tried the methods in the link you specified, but it didn't work. Still I cant stop the listener.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` of the useEffect runs when the screen is unmounted.

Navigating to a new screen will not unmount the old screen. Only an "orphaned" screen will be unmounted - i.e., on navigating back to screen A, screen B will be unmounted.

This scenario is described here in the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/

To unmount when navigating away, an easy trick is to use the `useIsFocused` hook. You could save the listener in a ref.

```js
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  const listener = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    listener.current = AppState.addEventListener('change', state => console.log(state));
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFocused && listener.current) {
      listener.current.remove();
    }
  }, [isFocused, listener]);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately nothing changed. Maybe navigating to a new screen won't unmount the old screen, but the function you typed in return of the useEffect will work when you navigate to the other screen. You can see this by adding a console.log to the return. .remove() isn't working for some reason, otherwise adding  appStateListener.remove() to return of useEffect would have sufficed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, can you elaborate?  It's working for me.  Did you use `import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native'`?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are navigating to Screen B, Screen A is not unmounted. Therefore, the code `appStateListener.remove();` will not get executed.

One suggestion would be to add `appStateListener` to the global level (maybe in the App.js) since the app state will be used on many screens as the app grows and handling the listener in a centralized place will be helpful when the app grows too.

Therefore, I don't see any downside of adding it as a global listener.
Let's discuss more on that if anybody has a better idea. Because I also wanna find the best practice.

Comment: Try writing a console.log() to the return of a useEffect and navigate to another screen. Then you will see that console.log executed.